# Sql Server Reporting

Tags: sql-server, reporting, ssrs-2016

I have a report parameter which depends on a query from the Dataset. The query needs one parameter and sql server reporting has no parameter drop down

version - Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Report Builder

[image]

Comment: @McNets added version in description

Comment: What happens when you click OK. Any errors ?

Comment: Yes its telling that DataSet2 procedure wants one parameter and there is not field for passing it

Comment: I am really interested in knowing the answer. Can you post the question on stackoveflow.com as well ?

Comment: I will repost it there too

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627779/ssrs-two-datasets-need-to-use-field-from-one-dataset-as-a-parameter-in-second?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Dataset parameters are not defined there.

To define the "value" of the parameter, you have to edit the dataset itself. That's where you will specify what value you want your query to run with; you can use a static value, or a report parameter.

If you use a report parameter as the value for your dataset, the dataset will not execute until the report parameter value is defined by the user. This will make the report behave like, "the values of parameter 2 only become available after selecting parameter 1".

Hope it helps.